# Facebook FQL: Get group post status photos

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I am trying to pull the photos from a user's post within a group.  Posts in a group seem to be either created as a 'photo' or 'status'.

I am able to pull the photos from a post within the group when it is created as a 'photo' using this:

```
SELECT attachment FROM stream WHERE post_id="<postid>"
```

But if the post was created as a 'status' this query doesn't return any data for the attachment.

Here is an example of a post created as a 'status' and what the results are. No data for attachment (photo) when I know there is a photo that goes with that post.

```
SELECT attachment, type, message, created_time FROM stream WHERE post_id = '<postid>'

{
  "data": [
    {
      "attachment": {
        "description": ""
      }, 
      "type": 308, 
      "message": "Ceramic wall hanging with mirror from Spain (6\"x8\") $5 pickup in SR",  
      "created_time": 1379101402
    }
  ]
}
```

Is this a permissions thing or am I just not pulling from the correct table(s) for this type of post?

Thanks
Chris

Comment: Same thing is happening for me. Very strange

Answer (score 1):

Just saying that it works fine for me:

```
SELECT post_id, attachment, type, message, created_time FROM stream WHERE post_id="POST_ID"
```

`POST_ID` looking like: `481234567779150_559912345679366`. The permissions I use are `user_groups` and `user_friends`.

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "post_id": "481234567779150_559912345679366", 
      "attachment": {
        "media": [
          {
            "href": "https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=10123450&set=gm.5599123456789366&type=1&relevant_count=1", 
            "alt": "bla bla bla", 
            "type": "photo", 
            "src": "https://fbcdn-photos-f-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-prn1/1013188_102013456789034740_1177097408_s.jpg", 
            "photo": {
              "aid": "65904234567838363", 
              "pid": "65904345678990795", 
              "fbid": "10202345678934740", 
              "owner": 1533245678910, 
              "index": 1, 
              "width": 1032, 
              "height": 581, 
              "images": [
                {
                  "src": "https://fbcdn-photos-f-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-prn1/1013188_10123456789_1177097408_s.jpg", 
                  "width": 130, 
                  "height": 73
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        ], 
        "name": "", 
        "caption": "", 
        "description": "", 
        "properties": [
        ], 
        "icon": "https://fbstatic-a.akamaihd.net/rsrc.php/v2/yz/r/StEh3RhPvjk.gif", 
        "fb_object_type": "photo", 
        "fb_object_id": "65123456789090795"
      }, 
      "type": 308, 
      "message": "bla bla bla", 
      "created_time": 1373368884
    }
  ]
}
```

Did you try your query in the [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?fql=SELECT%20post_id%2C%20attachment%2C%20type%2C%20message%2C%20created_time%20FROM%20stream%20WHERE%20post_id%3D%22POST_ID%22)? Can you give more information? What kind of group is it, secret, public? Is the user one of your friend? I personally tried with both public or private groups and friend or non-friend posts. Can you confirm this happens with other `308`-type posts with a photo and on several groups?